# Validity of Substitutions in Integrals

Tags: integration

In integrals, we often make 'u' substitutions, which involve writing $u=f(x)$, and then also writing $du=f'(x)dx$. How valid is this? I've heard that you aren't allowed to do things like 'break' up derivatives like they do to solve first order differential equations. So can you do this with integrals, or is it *also* a mnemonic?