# What does dx mean?

Tags: calculus, integration

For example when integrating by substitution one would write dx=2u.du. In this what does the dx mean and why do we get it in equations like the above? What i am basically asking is why does x=u^2 mean that dx=2u.du where do the du and dx come from??

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143222/what-does-dx-mean?rq=1

Comment: Until you get to higher calculus where such things are justified, I think that things like $\frac{du}{dx}=2x\implies dx=2xdu$ are, to put it uncharitably, meaningless gibberish. I'm just a student, but I have yet to see a single rigorous justification for manipulations like that. It does *work*, so presumably there is a justification, but personally I choose to see it as invalid, and prefer to write everything out in terms of functions and derivatives.

Comment: I just found this webpage it has some useful info http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65462.html

Comment: See also this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665438/validity-of-substitutions-in-integrals

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative it is basically notation to represent derivative wrt to x.